# XPath with ancestor returning the parent, not the node expected

Tags: javascript, xpath, jest-puppeteer

I have the following code

```
<div class="editor-options">
    <div class="editor-item">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-item">
        <label>Data Source</label>
        <div class="react-select-component css-2b097c-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-item" >
        <label>Attribute</label>
        <div class="react-select-component css-2b097c-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-item">
        <label>Type</label>
        <div class="type-select css-2b097c-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to find and select the two 'react-select-component' nodes independently by xpath (Data Source and Attribute)

These are dynamically created react-dropdown lists and have unique class names and content based on database values.

When I try to use:

$x("//div[contains(@class, 'react-select-component')]/ancestor::div[@class='editor-item']//label[contains(text(), 'Data Source')]")

The //label is returned not the //div[class='react-select-component'] which is what I expect. My understanding of Xpath/ancestor is:

Return the node:

//div[contains(@class, 'react-select-component')]

With the Ancestor:

/ancestor::div[@class='editor-item']//label[contains(text(), 'Data Source')]

Do I have it backwards?

Answer (score 1):

Since the output contains the `label` within the `div` you specified, you can use the `following-sibling` axe to locate nodes relative to that node on this specific tree. What I mean:

`//div[contains(@class, 'react-select-component')]/ancestor::div[@class='editor-item']//label[contains(text(), 'Data Source')]/following-sibling::div`

In case you want to be more specific, or want to avoid getting the wrong div (considering the existence of more than one), add more restrictions to that sibling.

Working [example](http://xpather.com/hLP7OtFS).

Comment: Interesting, yes that works. I haven't used following-sibling before but it must follow the same conventions of ancestor or parent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The last element in the expression is returned

```
1) //div[contains(@class, 'react-select-component')]
2) ancestor::div[@class='chart-editor-item']
3) label[contains(text(), 'Data Source')]
```

That's why `label` element is returned.
This xpath returns the expected element

```
//div[contains(@class,'editor-item') and child::label[contains(text(), 'Data Source')]]/div[contains(@class, 'react-select-component')]
```

That reads: "get a div with @class containing editor-item and a child `label` with value 'Data Source'"

```
//div[contains(@class,'editor-item') and child::label[contains(text(), 'Data Source')]]
```

given that div, get a child div with @class containing react-select-component

```
div[contains(@class, 'react-select-component')]
```

Using [xml2xpath.sh](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath) to check relevant xpaths

```
xml2xpath.sh -s '//div[contains(@class,"editor-item") and child::label[contains(text(), "Data Source")]]' -t -l test.html 
Namespaces:

  xml http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace

XML tree:

div
  label
  div

Found XPath:

//div[contains(@class,"editor-item") and child::label[contains(text(), "Data Source")]]
//div[contains(@class,"editor-item") and child::label[contains(text(), "Data Source")]]
//div[contains(@class,"editor-item") and child::label[contains(text(), "Data Source")]]/label
//div[contains(@class,"editor-item") and child::label[contains(text(), "Data Source")]]/div
```

Comment: Ah great explanation, I don't use these parent/child relationship expressions enough to remember the return order. Now I'll keep this as a reference.